# Setting parent of current view to null using the view's listener

Tags: android, garbage-collection, android-imageview, onclicklistener, android-tablelayout

I would like to set the parent of a particular `View` to `null` by using the View's `OnClickListener`.I am worried about performance and using too much memory because I have not set all of it's children to null:

```
  View.OnClickListener imageClickListener=new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v instanceof ImageView)
        {   
            rows.remove(rows.indexOf((TableRow)v.getParent()));
            table.removeView((TableRow)v.getParent());
            TableRow parent=(TableRow)v.getParent();
            parent.removeAllViews();
            parent=null;
        }
    }
};
```

Am I being paranoid,I worry because the code allows for adding and 'removing' `Views` dynamically to/from the layout without recycling `Views`.

Comment: Is there a problem you are trying to solve by this?

Comment: I would like to allow the user to add and remove phone numbers at will when saving to contacts,wouldn't it be better if the memory did not pile up,the user could use 5 of these and still have 4 or 5 removed values.This code removes the row from tablelayout

Comment: Unless there is a known issue, I would rather depend on the garbage collection than try to optimise by myself.